# How can I modify IamInstanceProfile in a Jenkins Slave template ec-2 plugin?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, groovy

I am trying to modify IamInstanceProfile in Jenkins AWC EC-2 plugin slave template configuration but it's not working.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.node_monitors.*
import hudson.slaves.*
import java.util.concurrent.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.plugins.ec2.*
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.*

jenkins = Hudson.instance
def now = new Date()
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def clouds = instance.clouds
def temp=instance.clouds[0].getTemplates()[0]
println temp.getIamInstanceProfile()
def riRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
riRequest.setIamInstanceProfile(new IamInstanceProfileSpecification().withArn(temp.getIamInstanceProfile()));
println riRequest
Jenkins.instance.save()
```

It executes without any error but without updating the IamInstanceProfile.

Comment: Define _"it's not working"_... Errors?

Comment: Updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out from https://github.com/jenkinsci/ec2-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/ec2/SlaveTemplate.java and found out iamInstanceProfile is a read-only property.